# Identify which MudExpansionPanel is being expanded

Tags: rendering, blazor-server-side, mudblazor

I want to present a list of up to 20 panels within a <MudExpansionPanels> component where the expanded child portion of each <MudExpansionPanel> is expensive to render. I tried the following test code but all instances of <LiveAgentSummary> are rendered as the parent  is rendered, just to clarify this rendering of <LiveAgentSummary> happens before any panel is manually expanded.

```
<MudExpansionPanels>
    @foreach (var liveAgent in _liveAgents)
    {
        <MudExpansionPanel Text=@liveAgent.Name>
            <LiveAgentSummary AgentId=@liveAgent.Id />
        </MudExpansionPanel>
    }
</MudExpansionPanels>
```

I then looked into delaying the render of each <LiveAgentSummary> through use of a RenderFragment that is dynamically built during the <MudExpansionPanel> IsExpandedChanged event. However the event handler does not indicate which panel is being expanded and hence I do not know which liveAgent.Id param value to pass to <LiveAgentSummary> as I build a RenderFragment.

I think <MudExpansionPanels> is missing support for a bind-ActivePanelId property but hopefully I am overlooking an alternative solution to my delayed rendering objective.

This is the [official MudBlazor example](https://mudblazor.com/components/expansionpanels#async-loading-of-data) that prompted me to look into using a RenderFragment.

**Update:** A long answer briefly appeared yesterday suggesting that I could query the list of panel components on a built-in property that indicates the expanded state. The poster had gone to the trouble of reading the MudBlazor source code but the answer was then deleted.

I am now wondering how from code in an event handler it is possible to iterate over a component hierarchy declared as mark-up. Applying this to my example markup above, how could event handler code obtain a reference to each <MudExpansionPanel> child within <MudExpansionPanels>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you make use of the `bool` from the `IsExpandedChanged` callback? Something like this:

#### Index.razor

```cs
@page "/"

<MudExpansionPanels>
  @foreach (var liveAgent in this.liveAgents)
  {
    <MudExpansionPanel
      Text="@($"{liveAgent.Name} ({liveAgent.Data})")"
      IsExpandedChanged="@(e => this.Load(e, liveAgent))">

      <LiveAgentSummary Agent="@liveAgent" />
    </MudExpansionPanel>
  }
</MudExpansionPanels>

@code {
  private readonly List<Agent> liveAgents = new()
  {
    new Agent("1", "Agent Smith"),
    new Agent("2", "Agent Brown"),
    new Agent("3", "Agent Jones")
  };

  private void Load(bool expanded, Agent agent)
  {
    if (expanded)
    {
      agent.Load();
    }
  }
}
```

#### LiveAgentSummary.razor

```cs
<MudText>id: @this.Agent.Id, data: @this.Agent.Data</MudText>

@code {
  [Parameter]
  public Agent Agent { get; set; } = default!;
}
```

#### Agent.cs

```cs
public record Agent(string Id, string Name)
{
  public string Data { get; set; } = "Not loaded";

  public void Load()
  {
    Console.WriteLine($"Loading agent {this.Id}...");

    this.Data = "Loaded!";
  }
}
```

Comment: I appriciate your time spent coding a full working example. I was previously fixated on producing a solution with a standard c# EventCallback<bool> method which has no context for the liveAgent in the razor foreach loop. Declaring an inline handler as an expression within the markup where liveAgent is visible, is a trick I won't forget. The Razor to C# code generator is using a closure within the foreach I assume.